# How to display current time with the ffplay.exe?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to play video files by the ffplay (or the ffmpeg if is it possible) and display current play time.

Please tell me how can I see the current play time (as H:M:S) with ffplay?

OS = MS Windows 7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: rgbtestsrc filter]

```
ffplay -vf "drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':box=1:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh)" input.mp4
```

- If your build does not support fontconfig, then you'll have to add the `fontfile` option with the path to the font. See [drawtext filter docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) for more info.
- In Windows you may have to first set the `FONTCONFIG_PATH` variable (and/or other related variables).
- You can add `boxborderw=4` if you want more padding in the box, but you'll need a relatively recent build. See the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page.

Comment: I could only get a second timecode using `%{pts}`, but not `hh:mm:ss` via `{pts:hms}`, not until I got all my quoting exactly correct (single, double, backslash), exactly as shown; i.e., `ffplay -vf "...text='{pts\:hms}' ..."`

Comment: Is it possible to remove the miliseconds and let only HH:MM:SS?

Comment: @RicardoBohner https://stackoverflow.com/a/67409424/

Answer (score 1):

For more options, there's [this tip](https://twitter.com/FFmpeg/status/1189602048313946112?s=20&t=yk1Ya4B9dok-O-vnb0JkPA), direct from FFMPEG on Twitter:

```
-vf "drawtext=text='%{pts\:hms}':fontsize=48:fontcolor=white:box=1:boxborderw=6:boxcolor=black@0.75:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-text_h-20"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

How to use drawtext displays the current localtime on windows

ffmpeg.exe -re -i "c:\aaa.avi" -vf drawtext="fontfile=simhei.ttf:fontsize=14:fontcolor=white:shadowcolor=black:shadowx=2:shadowy=1:x=8:y=8:text='???'" -q 5 -s 720*405 -aspect 16:9 -r 15 -threads 4 -vcodec flv -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -ab 64k -ac 2 -f flv "rtmp://127.0.0.1/aaa/flv"

[Maybe this helps](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=513)

Comment: Thanks ,But I get this error : RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 10061 (Unknown error)
rtmp://127.0.0.1/aaa/flv: Unknown error occurred

Comment: Also I need to display current play time of video.( no current localtime)

Comment: Did you follow the link "Maybe this helps" in the comment?

Comment: Yes I did , but it doesn't work for me.