# ffplay overlay current timestamp while playing not packaged video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, image-filter

I'm trying to create an overlay of the current timestamp while playing raw H.265 video with `ffplay` using [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) filter.

While overlay of the current frame number works fine with:

```
ffplay -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial.ttf: text='%{n}':box=1:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh)" video.265
```

I'm not able to display current timestamp like described in [this post](https://superuser.com/a/969596/354936) using `text='%{pts\:hms}'`. Using this my rendered output looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

I understand that raw H.265 file does not have any timing information, so this is probably the reason why I can't use `pts\:hms`.

My question is, is it possible to use the current frame number like in `text='%{n}'` but divide it by the framerate something like `text='%{n/24}'`? Unfortunately `text='%{n/24}'` is not allowed and `text='%{n}/24'` also doesn't work:

[image: screenshot2]

Just an info. I packaged the raw video into mp4 file `ffmpeg -i video.265 -c:v copy video.mp4` and then the command from the post above works just fine. But I'm still curious if it is possible to do some computation inside drawtext filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `eif` function

```
ffplay -vf \
       "drawtext=fontfile=/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Arial.ttf: \
        text='%{eif\:trunc(n/3600/24)\:d\:2}\:%{eif\:trunc(n/60/24)\:d\:2}\:%{eif\:trunc(mod(n*24\,60))\:d\:2}: \
        box=1:x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh)" \
video.265
```

This produces a HH:MM:SS output, and expects a 24 fps video stream.

Comment: Works but with `n` instead of `t`. using `t` I have following error: Expression 'trunc(t/60)' for the expr text expansion function is not valid

Comment: For a raw stream, `t` isn't assigned or calculated. Updated command.